# How to dynamically scroll to the top of a listbox

Tags: ios, delphi, listbox, scroll, delphi-xe5

I have a delphi iOS application via Delphi xe5. on Form1, I have a button that generates results for a Listbox in form2 and then shows form2 after loading the items for that box. My issue is that when I go back to form1, and load results again: this time when Form2 appears, the listbox's display is in the middle of the screen. Meaning, instead of displaying results starting from the top, results are being displayed mid-way down the whole list of contents.

How do I programmatically have the list box scroll to the top of the results? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the listbox's ItemIndex to be zero:

```
Listbox1.ItemIndex := 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that setting ItemIndex := 0 only worked if the user had clicked on a listbox item while viewing the list. Instead, I have used this code and it is working every time:

```
var
  THackListBox = type TListBox;
begin
  THackListBox(ListBox1).VScrollBar.Value := 0;
```

The VScrollBar property is protected but this method exposes the property and allows the value to be set to zero.